# Exclude Author by ID

Tags: author, exclude, list-authors

How can I exclude authors by ID from this:

```
<?php
//displays all users with their avatar and their posts (titles)
$blogusers = get_users_of_blog();
if ($blogusers) {
  foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
    echo '<div class="content-slider-body">';
    $user = get_userdata($bloguser->user_id);
    echo '<div class="grid col-140">' . get_avatar( $user->ID, 128 ) . '</div>';
    $args=array(
      'author' => $user->ID,
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1
    );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      //echo 'List of Posts for ' . user->user_firstname . ' ' . $user->user_lastname;
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where `$that_user_your_filtering_out` is the user/author ID you wan't to filter out, make this modification to your loop

```
foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
    // modification starts here
    if($bloguser->user_id == $that_user_your_filtering_out){
        continue;
    }
    // modification ends here
    echo '<div class="content-slider-body">';
    $user = get_userdata($bloguser->user_id);
```

Comment: Tom, can this be modified for multiple user IDs? I tried array(1,2) but that didn't work.

Comment: well the question "Is 1 the same as 1,2,3,4,5,6 " explains why it doesn't work. Instead use the `in_array` function http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. This works to exclude multiple users:
`// modification starts here
    $excluded_users = array(1,3); // User Ids to exclude
 if (in_array($bloguser->user_id, $excluded_users)){
        continue;
    }
    // modification ends here`

Comment: =] Glad you got it working